# Keep the prefab connection when updating FBX asset

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx

The steps I have perform:

1. Added an Fbx to Unity Project
2. FBX added to scene hierarchy
3. Make the Prefab of the FBX
4. Some assignment to prefab

Everything is working fine. I did assignment to prefab **NOT FBX**. Now the problem is when I importing the updated FBX, my scene object didn't updated as it links with  prefab not With updated FBX. The connection of my hierarchy game object is now with prefab not with FBX. So, if I replace the FBX then, the hierarchy game object will not be update as it links with prefab not directly with updated FBX.

Is this possible to update my prefab with latest FBX** so I didn't assign again and again to my script.

OR
Any else solution.? 
***I guess this is the really general question which frequently face by Unity Developers. Please help.***

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution that I've found for this problem is to bypass Unity's asset import system, and directly overwrite the FBX asset in your project's assets directory (eg. Copy/pasting through Windows Explorer).

Note that this will probably not work if your model has a rig/skeleton applied, and you've changed them/their relationship with the model in some way since the last version.

In those cases, I would advise just re-importing the model and setting up your prefabs again, or you'll start encountering some very peculiar behaviours. (Note that only changing animations/keyframes on a model has never created this problem for me, so in those cases you can stick to my original suggestion. Naturally you might have to change the frame ranges over which your animations are defined, though.)

Hope this helps! This is a bit of a workaround, but it has worked well for my workflow when I just want to quickly update and test assets.

Comment: i guess u didnt understand my problem, explorer is replace the fbx but my prefab don't

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan You're right, I guess I didn't understand the problem, because it wasn't indicated in your problem description that you were doing anything except for Unity's standard asset import workflow. I just attempted this in a new scene however, and can confirm that importing a mesh, making geometry changes to it, then overwriting the original in Windows Explorer works just fine. So what problem is it that you're facing? Please edit your question to indicate specifically why your current approach isn't working, preferably with screenshots for clarity.

Comment: if i replace the fbx then, the hirarchy gameobject will not be updated as it links with prefab not directly with updated FBX.